# Regex n 0 and then a 1

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex to match n zeros and then a 1. 
E.g:

```
0000100 -> matches
00200 -> does not math
```

I thought it was something like that:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[0]*[2-9]+");
```

Comment: You regex matches zero or more 0 followed by one or more of any digit from 2 to 9. that sounds like the opposite of what you are trying to do

Comment: Where is the `1` in your regex?

Comment: what do you mean by n zeros? Is that defined or any number of zeros?

Comment: Are `1`, `01bla-bla-bla`  valid strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Linq* solution (and no *regular expression*):

```
string source = "0001";

bool isValid = source
  .SkipWhile(c => c == '0')
  .FirstOrDefault() == '1';
```

If you insist on regular expression:

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(source, "^0*1");
```

In both cases *zero* or more `0` followed by `1`

Answer (score 4):

`^[0]+[1]` is what you want:

`^` start of line

`[0]` match 0

`+` at least once

`[1]` match 1

You could also add a `$` at the end, if you want it to match a complete line.

Note: if you want to be able to match n=0 (i.e. just a 1), you need:
`^[0]*[1]`

Note: the brackets `[]` are optional as they only contain one character, but I think they make it easier to read. So you could have `^0+1` if you prefer, for example.

See also http://regexstorm.net/reference (for example) for a complete C# regex reference

Comment: I don't think OP wants the 1 to be at the end of the line (according to the provided example for matches)

Comment: Why must use `[]`?

Comment: @UnholySheep just noticed that, updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: @TânNguyễn just habit - makes it clearer what's going on.

Comment: I haven't read any document said that before. No need to wrap single character by `[]` except you want to ignore it: `[^0]`

Comment: `[1]` is redundant, just `1` will be enough

Comment: Yes, I know that [1] and [0] are redundant - I do say as much in my answer (that `[]` are optional) - I just prefer it for clarity. Does it add any overhead?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of regex here: left-trim the string from `0`, and if it is not null or empty, check the first char.

```
var s = "00001";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.TrimStart('0')) &&
     s.TrimStart('0').Substring(0, 1) == "1") 
{ 
    /* Valid, otherwise, not */ 
}
```

*This will work if you have the digits at the beginning of the string and just need  a  boolean result.*